# SAS: std value missing

Tags: sas

The following code return a missing value for std. Why is that? And what's the rule for std function set to missing?

(This data has a mean of 3)

```
DATA example;

    INPUT x1-x3;
    std = STD(OF x1-x3);
    DATALINES; 
    3.. 

RUN;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 2 values to calculate a standard deviation.

variance = sum( (x-xmean)**2 ) / (n-1);
std = sqrt(variance);

With n=1 you have a divide by 0 error;